# Magento 2 SEO Multi-stores share CMS pages

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, frontend, multistore, seo

I built a module that supposed to solve the following issue:
a multi-site setup with some CMS pages that are shared across the different websites. The problem that we are having is that this is causing duplicate content issues and affecting the SEO rankings.
As well I have to add a new config in the admin area which will be filled with store language that is different than magento language for example "en-us" and "en-gb" this because the meta tag must have specific values for each country.

The meta tag will be structures as follows:

I have uploaded the code to GitHub repo:

https://github.com/AAbbadi/M2-Language

I want someone to let me know if this repo will solve the issue ? as well what is the best practice to solve this.

P.S: I'm Magento self learner. and I was unable to find someone close to me that can help me!

Comment: Hello Alaa, can you please clarify what expected from this module and what went wrong?

Comment: Hello Elwan, well the idea from this module is if you have multi stores in same magento environment and they share same CMS page for example "contact us" page, then i need to make sure that the meta tag language will change based on the running store, the language will be set from a new config that i created in the admin panel. this module supposed to fix the duplicate content issue for SEO.

Comment: I have explained the my situation more.